# Non-parametric statistical test with one measurement variable and two nominal variables

Tags: nonparametric, categorical-data

I have the following data: feces density of a carnivore species subdivided according to sex. I am looking for appropriate test suggestions.
I have calculated the density according to main habitat types, topography, and road types. To determine if results are statistically significant, I would believe the Friedman`s test or Wilcoxon signed-rank test would apply in this case since there is one measurement variable (feces density) and two nominal variables (e.g., habitat type and sex; road type and sex; topography and sex) and both are non-parametric statistical tests.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "To determine if results are statistically significant" is too vague to be meaningful. What are your hypotheses and research questions? Is there a dependent variable?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.     My research questions are:                  -Which areas and habitats are preferred by males and which are preferred by females? -Are there any differences or similarities?  My hypotheses are: -Females prefer the lowlands and males the highlands. -Males are more common along roads frequently used by humans. -Both sexes have different habitat use preferences.  The dependent variable would be scat density. Sex, besides being a nominal variable, would also be a dependent one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Going from your comment-*Which areas and habitats are preferred by males and which are preferred by females?* Here you probably want regression with scat density as the DV and sex and habitat as IVs (and possibly their interaction). However, if you have repeated measures over time on the same animals, you might need a multilevel model (this assumes you have scat density and can tell which scat is from males and females).

*-Are there any differences or similarities?* This can be looked at with descriptive statistics

*Sex, besides being a nominal variable, would also be a dependent one.*

Sex cannot be a DV. Sex is not caused by habitat! (Except, I suppose, for some hermaphroditic animals)

Comment: I think the idea behind sex as a DV was to predict "sex of observed carnivore" from location of observation.